# Is there a Django way of comparing the results of a test to a fixture?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm trying to understand fixtures and unit tests in Django. I can successfully load a fixture and use the data in my unit test.

What I want to do is **compare the results of the test to a second fixture**, `fixture_2`, which represents how the data *should* look.

Here's a step-by-step of what I am talking about:

1. Import `fixture_1`, generating the initial test data.
2. Run the test on the data, changing it.
3. Somehow compare the results of the test to `fixture_2`.

Is there a way to do step 3? Should I somehow overwrite the test database with `fixture_2` and do the assertions from there, or is there a way of comparing the test database to a fixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture file is JSON data. You could use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to load the data and then do your comparisons? Something like:

```
import json

self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.all().count(), len(json.loads(fixture_2)))
```